# Closed sets in $~\mathbb R^3~$, topology

Tags: general-topology

A singleton set is closed in $~\mathbb R~$ and $~\mathbb R^2~$, but it is not closed in $~\mathbb R^3~$. Why? We can say a singleton set is not closed in $~\mathbb R^3~$ as its complement is not open. But how do we prove this?
Also I can say since in $~\mathbb R~$ complement of every singleton set is open thus the singleton set is closed and same goes for  $~\mathbb R^2~$. (I hope I am correct). As in space $~\mathbb R~,~\mathbb R$ \ $\{x\}~$ can give union of two open sets.

Comment: In $\Bbb{R}^n$, for **every** $n$, all singleton sets are closed. As soon as you have a sensible notion of distance (a metric), you know that singleton sets are closed. I don't know who told you otherwise, but they're wrong.

Comment: In fact every finite set is closed in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Why do you believe singletons are not closed in $\mathbb R^3$? What's different about higher dimensional spaces?

Answer (score 1):

For any positive integer $n$, in standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. one induced by the Euclidean metric, a singleton set $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $x$. Therefore, the singleton sets are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is closed in $\Bbb{R}^n$ because, if $p \in \Bbb{R}^n$, then
$$\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\} = \bigcup_{x \in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}} B(x; \|x - p\|),$$
where $B(x; \|x - p\|)$ is the open ball, centred at $x$, with radius $\|x - p\|$.

To see why this is true, any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}$ is contained in the right hand side, because it is the centre of one of the balls in the union. On the other hand, $p$ is not in the right hand side, because it doesn't lie in any of the open balls in the union (it lies in their boundary spheres, but since the balls are open, it doesn't lie in the balls themselves).

This means that $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}$ is the union of a family of open sets, which implies it is open, and its complement $\{p\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R^n$ is a metric space, and any metric space is $T_1$.  That's equivalent to saying that points are closed.